# Fetch MySql database from cocoa app - PHP bridging

Tags: php, mysql, database, cocoa

I'm trying to download a range of rows from my MySql database, through a cocoa app that I'm developing. I use a php that receives an index from my app and sends back all the rows up to that index.
My cocoa code is:

```
NSInteger index = 0;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/test.php?index=%d&", index];

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];

NSLog(@"%@", [items description]);
```

When the php receive the `GET` variable `index` it runs this code:

```
$index = $_GET['index'];
$Keys = array(...);

mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password) or die("Unable to connect to database"); 
mysql_select_db($Database) or die("Unable to select database");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM transactions where id > $index ORDER BY id");

$plist = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
$plist .= "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">\n";
$plist .= "<plist version=\"1.0\">\n";
$plist .= "<array>\n";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $plist .= "\t<dict>\n";

    foreach($Keys as $key){
        $plist .= "\t\t<key>$key</key>\n";
        $plist .= "\t\t<string>$row[$key]</string>\n";
    }

    $plist .= "\t</dict>\n";
}

$plist .= "</array>\n";
$plist .= "</plist>";

echo $plist;

unset($_GET['index']);
```

This all works fine if there are up to 30 rows from `index` and the last id of the database! If, from my cocoa code, I set `index` to request up to 30 rows or I set `index` to zero (to request all the database) ... the `NSArray` object contains nothing!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry! I've solved by myself! There was an encoding issue!
Just changed:

```
utf8_encode($row[$key])
```

and I've solved the problem!

Answer (score 3):

This won't answer your question, but your code is wide open to a sql injection attack.  The way to fix it is a very simple sprintf:

```
$result = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM transactions where id > %d ORDER BY id", intval($index)));
```

Now, if a malicious user tries to inject text into the $index variable, then the intval + sprintf combination will just turn it into the number 0, thereby protecting your db.